# Google Tag Manager _ga querystring issue

Tags: google-tag-manager

I am facing a weird issue with GTM.
I have one main domain and several sub-domains.
I have main site on http:://abc.com and I have ads delivering from http://ads.abc.com
Now GTM automatically ads the _ga tag to the banner pointing to an outside domain. I am fine with it adding the _ga tag but the querystring starts with "&" instead of starting it with "?" that breaks the url pointing to the banner. 
Here is my url to the banner:
http://ads.abc.org/www/delivery/ck.php?oaparams=2__bannerid=103__zoneid=11__cb=4e3789c636__oadest=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.outsideurl.com.com%2Fsolution&_ga=1.35617777.1606009999.1489075858

Does GTM has some kind of configuration where I can define ads.abc.com as a part of abc.com and it wouldn't add cross-domain _ga tag OR is there anything where I can prevent the _ga tag from being added to the url starting with ads.petrowiki.org

I am using Revive ad server to deliver the ads. I know for sure that it has nothing to do with the Ad server but just in case..

Answer (score 0):

That is the [Google Analytics cross-domain "Linker" feature](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/linker), which may or may not be related to your GTM implementation.

You can disable it by removing the `ga('require', 'linker');` command or disabling `linker:autoLink`.

If you are configuring GA via GTM, you can add a "Field to Set" setting of `allowLinker`, value `false`.

Comment: Chris, where it is defined? is it in Tags, Triggers or Variables? These are the three things I see when I login to my GTM account.

Comment: How is your Google Analytics integrated with your site? If you have added GA via GTM, you will find it in the Tags section.

Comment: Just to be totally clear, this is coming from Google Analytics, not Google Tag Manager itself.